# How to buy physical bitcoin in EU (Sweden)

Tags: cryptocurrency

I want to give a person one bitcoin in real life, preferably as a physical coin and not as a paper or a digital contract. IIUC it is possible somewhere to buy a physical bitcoin which is like a real coin. If I want to buy such an item in EU (Sweden), where should I go in order to minimize risk of fraud / fake coin, fair pricing and quick delivery?

Comment: Bitcoin is entirely electronic. That is the point of it. There is no mint. There is no metal. If you wanted to write the address to a bitcoin down on a scrap of paper (or embroider it on your own "DJ Saunders Bill") you could do that, but it's the same as if it was just in your phone or on your computer.

Answer (score 4):

Be VERY wary of physical representations of bitcoin.  DO NOT, buy a paper wallet from anyone that has bitcoin loaded to an address that you did not provide.  Addresses include a private and a public component, if someone has your private key they can spend the coin.  You NEVER want to buy a physical anything with a public address written on it, because that person has access to the private key and can simply spend the coin the moment you're gone.

Bitcoin is just a public ledger, xyz address has 4BTC.  You can literally look up all the transactions and current balance of any bitcoin address with a [block chain explorer](https://blockchain.info/).  There is no such thing as a physical bitcoin.  There is such thing as control over the private key.  If you have control of the private key you can spend the coins at the address.